# How I can block to change view in list SharePoint Foundation

Tags: list, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, permissions, list-view

How I can block change view in ShrePoint list?Even when I add user Read Only permission to some list, person be able to change view in this list. I want to block change view but I don't know how. I tried creating new permission level but in every level person be able to change view.

I use SharePoint Foundation and SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 1):

you can disable it for groups by following this link,

http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint_blank/archive/2009/06/08/can-view-capabilities-be-disabled-within-sharepoint-groups.aspx

hope it helped :)

Comment: I did this but I still be able to change view in list? I uchecked Manage list and Manage personal View but it didn't help?